# Recurring stalls in SwapBuffer

Tags: opengl, performance

I am currently doing measurements on a test scene implemented in OpenGL 4.5 with different "setups".

I noticed that in case I have a very high amount of FPS (1550 in this specific case), SwapBuffer does stall about every 20th frame and the frame time increases from ~0.5ms to ~1.2ms.
This does ONLY happen when the FPS is above a certain threshold.
I already figured out that it is not related to pre-rendered frames (i disabled pre-rendered frames in the NV control panel) and it is also not related to vsync (`wglSwapIntervalEXT(0)` is used).

Can someone tell me what might be causing this stalls/lags or wathever.

I attached two screenshots made with Nsight.

The first shows a "healthy" setup with no stalls:
[image]

While the seconds shows the setup with the stalls:

[image]

Comment: What are you running that requires 1550 frames per second? The reason you're getting stalls every so often with such a refresh rate is probably because once an application gets behind (even just by a few frames) it can take a while for it to catch up. Large framerates amplify this problem. Maybe your troubles are because your computer can't handle such a large refresh rate.

Comment: Also many computers only update the screen 60 times per second, and the speed of the human eye is only so fast, so super-high FPS isn't too necessary anyway.

Comment: What hardware and software are you running? In shared environment OS can use GPU hardware for background tasks such as generating thumbnails, drop shadows, etc. This might be happening periodically, causing the stalls.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 and a GF 970 GTX. If it is related to background task, wouldn´t it mean these stalls may also occur in a lower FPS scenario?
And I dont need it to run a 1550, i just need to elaborate on the measuring results and why it behaves as it behaves with 1550 FPS. Therefore I also need some kind of "fact", which proves the statement in some way.

Comment: @Chris Have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829881/avoid-waiting-on-swapbuffers)?

Comment: @Chris Also could you produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: What is your processor usage when the stalling occurs? Could it be, that at such framerates, your CPU can't handle it, so the stall occurs? Have you tried setting process priority to above normal / high?

Comment: akaltar: I could not find any hints in the CPU usage. Seems normal. I tried with high and realtime priority but there was not change. 
@Soapy: I found this post already but I will read over it again. The most minimal example I tried, was just clearing the backbuffer and swapping. In this case the stalls already occur.

Comment: @Chris can you share the minimal example?

Comment: I will try to, but the code is quite encpasulated and very likely not the cause.
I talked to someone today working as a senior graphics developer and he told me that this is likely to happen because of the monitor not able to handle this high frame-rate, also referred to as high fps glitch.
Allthough I would still like an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately these kinds of unexplained stalls can be common, and very hard to answer perfectly.

To answer the question precisely, we would have to know what is happening inside the driver during that short stall. NVidia and AMD only provide us with so much information about their driver's behaviour. Sometimes we have to make guesses.

And sometimes the behaviour of the driver isn't perfectly logical. The drivers get optimised for the kinds of use cases required by current games. That can mean that other use cases end up less efficient. Running at 1550fps isn't a normal kind of situation, so we can't expect the driver to be optimised for this case.

One thing to consider is that GPU events are desynchronised from the CPU using a FIFO queue. The queue contains rendering commands (like bind-render-target, copy-memory-to-constant-buffer, draw-indexed, etc). The CPU writes commands to the queue. And at some desynchronised time, the GPU will read those commands from the queue. We can think of it as like a producer/consumer pattern.

In some cases, the CPU might run faster than the GPU. This means the queue will get longer and longer. For very simple frames, the queue could become several frames long.

There are few API commands to control how the driver manages this queue. So the driver has freedom to limit the size of the queue (even if that means synchronising the CPU and the GPU).

I think this might be the most likely explanation... The driver has probably decided that the CPU has become too far ahead of the GPU. And so it is injecting small pauses to slow down the CPU and allow the GPU to catch up.

There are other possibilities as well... Maybe the driver is doing some defragmentation work on GPU memory? It could even be that nsight is causing the stalls (maybe doing some work managing it's profiling buffers).

If you want to explore some more, there are some tools you can try:

**GPUView** -- http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/GPUView.html
This profiles events inside the windows driver model. You can even see some of the queuing behaviour, where packets of commands get stalled waiting for GPU time.

**Profile enabled drivers** -- If you have access to developer support at nvidia or AMD, they have tools that can profile their driver code. That can give an indication of what the driver is doing.

However, my real suggestion is to try profiling a real, practical case. The behaviour of the driver code and your engine code at 1550 frames is not really that important. If you can recreate the same stalling behaviour in a practical case (eg, rendering a game scene), then that might be something that is more productive to explore.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation!
I actually already used GPUView, however I dont have enough time left to familiarize myself with it and hence I dont understand a lot of its output.
Anyway your answer in conjunction with some things I found out myself is enough for me I guess, to elaborate on this. And as you say, this scenario is very fictional and not likely to be encountered in any production code ever.
I will accept you answer soon!
Regards Chris